# How to split a string?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsstring, stringwithformat, nsscanner

I have a string made of three strings like this

```
NSString *first = ..;
NSString *second = ..;
NSString *third = ..;

NSString joinedString;
joinedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ (%@)", first, second, third];
```

Now I need to get back the three original strings from `joinedString`. I've read somewhere that I should use `NSScanner` for this. Any ideas how that might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the example you provided in your question, you could do the following:

```
// characters we are going to split at
NSString *sep = @" -()";
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:sep];
NSArray *strings = [joinedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];

// This is the simple way provided that the strings doesn't have spaces in them.
```

I would use NSScanner with larger strings that have variable information and you want to find that needle in the haystack.

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString` won't work. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the exact pattern as mentioned in your post you can use NSRegularExpression (iOS 4+):

```
NSString *regexStr = @"(.*)\s-\s(.*)\s\((.*)\)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:joinedString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [joinedString length])];
NSString *string1 = [results objectAtIndex:0];
...
```

(no error handling and not able to verify it right now)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`:

```
NSString *chars = @"-()";
NSArray *split = [joinedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterset characterSetWithCharactersInString:chars]];
```

You can then trim the beginning/end spaces:

```
stringFromArray = [stringFromArray stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```